# Why use android:weightSum?

Tags: android, android-layout

If [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum) is not specified, Android will just add the weights of the children together. So, is there really a reason to use weightSum? Is there a situation where I shouldn't use it?

Is it more efficient than simply letting android add the weight by itself?

Comment: just a thought: if `weightSum=5` and sum of weights=6, then you're hiding part of the view. Similarly, if the sum is less than the weightSum, you will have some empty space. never tried that though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important word in the reference documentation description is "single": "This can be used for instance to give a **single** child 50% of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0." In this case, the sum of the weights of the children (in this case, only child) is different to the weightSum.

So you only need to use weightSum when you won't necessarily have the children filling the entire LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can set weightSum = 3 for your layout, and weight = 1 for two children views. In result your views will range 66.6% of all place in layout.

Good luck!